# Using lambda to create new list by altering/modifying old list

Tags: python, list, lambda

```
oldlist=['a','b','c']
print newlist=[(lambda x : x+x )(x) for x in oldlist ]
# Result: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Now I want to have the output like this:

```
newlist=['1a','2b','3c']
```

Hopefully I want to do it using lambda like this:

```
idx=1
newlist=[(lambda x : str(idx)+x ; idx+=1)(x) for x in oldlist ]
```

But I'm not allowed to use multiline expression in lambda. So how do I increment **idx** inside that lambda?

Comment: You don't ever need a lambda in that position.  `[(lambda x:expr)(x) for x in iteratorexpr]` is exactly equivalent to `[expr for x in iteratorexpr]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `lambda` at all.

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> oldlist = ['a','b','c']
>>> enumerate(oldlist)
<enumerate object at 0x7f5e58a455f0>
>>> list(enumerate(oldlist))  # default start = 0
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
>>> list(enumerate(oldlist, 1))  # explicitly specify `start`
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

---

```
>>> oldlist = ['a','b','c']
>>> [str(i) + x for i, x in enumerate(oldlist, 1)]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) iterator:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> it = itertools.count(1)  # yield 1, 2, 3, ... infinitely.
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
2
```

---

```
>>> import itertools
>>> it = itertools.count(1)
>>> [str(next(it)) + x for x in oldlist]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Comment: Thanks , it solves my problem. Btw what about if i want to for example increment by 5 --> [ '1a' , '6b' , '11c' ] etc .... seems that enumerate() doens't have parameter to control the step.

Comment: @andio, `[str(1 + 5 * i) + x for i, x in enumerate(oldlist)]`

Comment: @andio, With `itertools.count`: `it = itertools.count(1, 5)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increment inside `lambda`, you will have to pass incremented value from outside (If you must use lambda, as lambda is not needed here as suggested by @falsetru). Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and pass index to `lambda`.

```
newlist=[(lambda idx, x : str(idx)+x)(idx, x) for (idx, x) in enumerate(oldlist, 1) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `enumerate` with standard python list definitions:

```
>>> oldlist = ['a','b','c']
>>> newlist = [str(idx + 1) + e for idx, e in enumerate(oldlist)]
>>> print(newlist)
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```